# C Program : Array example

Tags: c, arrays, char, initialization, string-literals

I read somewhere that i should be able to initialize the array like that. but why isn't it working.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
   char s[10];
   s[10]="pen";
   printf("%s\n",s[10]);    
}
```

output:
NULL

Comment: Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

This is initialization: `char s[10] = "pen";`
This is assignment (and invalid syntax): `s[10]="pen";`

Similar syntax but different terms. Initialization is done together with the variable declaration. Generally, initialization could be carried out before the program is launched. Had you for example written `const char s[10] = "pen";`, then the string could be pre-loaded into the variable before the program starts.

Since `s[10]="pen";` is invalid C but your compiler let it through with a warning (which you probably didn't read), consider compiling with stricter compiler settings. On gcc this means compiling with `-pedantic-errors -Werror`, which I strongly recommend beginners to use.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking this statement

```
s[10]="pen";
```

is not an initialization. It is an assignment. You are trying to assign the string literal `"pen"` having the type `char *` to a non-existent element of the type `char` of the array `s` with the index `10`.

So the both these statements

```
s[10]="pen";
printf("%s\n",s[10]);
```

invoke undefined behavior.

Pay attention to that arrays have no the assignment operator. Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues. If you will write for example

```
s = "pen";
```

the compiler will issue an error.

What you need is the following

```
char s[10] = "pen";
printf("%s\n",s);
```

That is in this case the array `s` will be initialized with elements of the string literal. All elements that do not have a corresponding initializer of the string literal will be zero-initialized.

If to use assignments instead of the initialization then this declaration

```
char s[10] = "pen";
```

is equivalent to

```
char s[10];
s[0] = 'p';
s[1] = 'e';
s[2] = 'n';
s[3] = '\0';
s[4] = '\0';
s[5] = '\0';
s[6] = '\0';`
s[7] = '\0';
s[8] = '\0';
s[9] = '\0';
```

`

Answer (score 1):

After the array is declared, it is no longer an "initialization".

You are attempting an *assignment*.
But you **cannot** assign an entire array using the syntax: `s[10]="pen";`

```
main()
{
   char s[10] = "pen";    // Initialization
   printf("%s\n",s);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
   char s[10] = "pen";
   printf("%s\n",s);    
}
```

And you can't access `s[10]` as indexing start from `0` i.e `s[0]`-`s[9]`
Reason for `NULL` output is `len(s)` is `3`